# WP7 Listbox scrolling

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox

I created a simple application with nested ListBox and  strings in it.  If i scroll it really fast - there is empty spaces.Can i increase the rendering speed or
Can i slow down scrolling speed in ListBox somehow ?

Comment: May I ask why? Do the users actually comprehend the information that scrolls by "really fast"?

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to overcome the black occurrence on scrolling you need to virtualize your scroll control. For that you should inherit IList and create a Collection of your own similar to ObservableCollection in which you will have to override the default indexer depending on your caching requirement and simultaneously maintain a cache for your items. I feel this might be what you are looking for: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/16/virtualizing-data-in-windows-phone-7-silverlight-applications.aspx

There is a sample project on that page. Try that out.

I also feel that you are facing this problem http://blog.rsuter.com/?p=258. I guess this will be solved using virtualization itself. Hope it helps

Comment: That sounds like an awful lot of work. :) As a developer, I understand why he wants to do this. As a user (albeit with a developer mindset), I accept the blanks as a quirk of the platform.

Comment: I know thats a lot of work. I faced the same problem. Sometime tradeoff needs to be done. It helped me in my task thats why suggested it to him too :)

Comment: @MilanAggarwal why should we use IList? I think that ListBox support **UI virtualization** by default, using VirtualizingStackPanel. IList is useful for **data virtualization**, and it has nothing to do with black occurrence !

Comment: pls refer the link I have posted for better understanding. The answer for your question is explained there. Also please try the sample there with both normal list and custom list.

Answer (score 0):

The blog Milan posted is a good source to start with. Virtualizing data works by changing the item template of the list item while scrolling. This will not work up to the expectations when there is a complex layout.

But I suggest you work more on the layout you are working on. Having too many stack panels in order to make the layout a bit generic will destroy the performance.